# Move terminal panel to bottom option gone? (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just updated VSCode to `1.29.0` on macOS `10.12.6` and it looks like this option to move the terminal to the bottom of VSCode (and then back right) is no more. Is that on purpose? Did it move to a specific setting? I was using that feature quite a lot.

Here goes a screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT**:
Can still move by context menu:

[image]

Comment: Do you still have the context menu option to move right?

Comment: @Bob__ yes i can still move it by right clicking and selecting "Move panel to bottom".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT** for v1.42 (January 2020 release):

> **Panel on the left**
>
> The panel can now be moved to the left side of the editor with the
>   setting:
>
> `"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "left"`
>
> This removes the command
>   View: Toggle Panel Position (`workbench.action.togglePanelPosition`) in
>   favor of the following new commands:
>
> View: Move Panel Left (`workbench.action.positionPanelLeft`)
>
> View: Move Panel Right (`workbench.action.positionPanelRight`)
>
> View: Move Panel To Bottom (`workbench.action.positionPanelBottom`)

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#panel-on-the-left

---

[Previous answer - see above for later info:]

See [release notes on panel position button](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_panel-position-button-to-context-menu).

> Panel position button to context menu
>
> In order to preserve horizontal space and reduce clutter, we removed
>   the toggle Panel position button (Move to Right, Move to Bottom) from
>   the Panel title area. The action is now available in the Panel title
>   area context menu and also in View > Appearance > Toggle Panel
>   Position main menu. Another reason for removing this button was that
>   we believe users set their layout once and don't normally toggle back
>   and forth.

There is also this setting to "permanently" change the panel location:

```
workbench.panel.defaultLocation
```

But to move it on the fly now you use the context menu.

Apparently people just weren't using it enough to warrant the screen space.

Comment: Damn, it was very useful for me. Thanks for the info Mark.

Answer (score 10):

Just Click through the following:

`View > Appearance > Move Panel Right`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the panel at the bottom,

```
View > Appearance > Toggle Panel Position
```

Now drag and drop the terminal icon from the sidebar (left or right side) to panel bar (bottom)

Comment: This seems to have been replaced with "Move Panel Right" and "Move Panel to Bottom" in both the menu and command pallete.