# How do I dock the terminal window to the right in VS Code version 1.29.1?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated my VS Code installation to the latest version `1.29.1` and the ability to dock the terminal window to the right has seemingly gone. I can't find any way to do that.

Can you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move terminal to bottom option gone? (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302367/move-terminal-to-bottom-option-gone-vscode)

Comment: Thank you. Nice. Upvoted your answer. :-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can right click on the terminal "tab", where the "Terminal" text is displayed and click "Move Panel Right".

Comment: Thank you. :-) They had a command icon on the right-side of the terminal window in versions prior.

Comment: Yep, there's a comment here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_panel-position-button-to-context-menu

Comment: Lovely! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.  I was starting to get pretty irritated, thinking they'd removed it...