# Visual Studio Code Terminal bottom/top button missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know what happened to the bottom/top button when using the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?  The button was available in 1.27.  I am running 1.30.1; and I don't see it on the terminal's title bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move terminal to bottom option gone? (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302367/move-terminal-to-bottom-option-gone-vscode)